# Spell check program issues

Tags: c, dictionary, spell-checking, strcmp, strlen

I'm trying to finish my spell check project and am having a few issues. I'm trying to use `strlen` and `strcmp` to compare the words in the article and dictionary with each other, but the compiler tells me that the identifier "strlen" and "strcmp" are undefined. I'm not sure what to do here. Additionally, when I load `char(article)` into `int ArticleLength`, it tells me that I can't use int with char article. I'm very much a beginner and need some help. Here's my code so far.

```
#include <stdio.h> // provides declarations for printf and putchar
#include <stdint.h> // provides declarations for int32_t uint32_t and the other (new) standard C type
/* You must write this function (spellCheck). Do not change the way the function is declared (i.e., it has
 * exactly two parameters, each parameter is a standard (mundane) C string (see SpellCheck.pdf).
 * You are expected to use reasonable programming style. I *insist* that you indent 
 * reasonably and consistently in your code. I strongly encourage you to avoid big functions
 * (while there are always exceptions, a good rule of thumb is about 15 lines in a function).
 * So, plan on implementing spellCheck by writing two or three other "support functions" that
 * help make the actual spell checking easier for you.
 * There are no explicit restictions on using functions from the C standard library. However,
 * for this project you should avoid using functionality from the C++ standard libary. You will
 * almost certainly find it easiest to just write everything you need from scratch!
 */
void spellCheck(char article[], char dictionary[]){
int OneLetter(char c);
void MakeLower(char article[]);
void KillPunct(char article[]);
void LowerDictionary(char dictionary[]);
int ArticleLength(char article[]);
void ArticleNextWord(char article[], char ArticleWord[], int ArticleLength, char dictionary[]);
char ArticleWord[50];
char DictionaryWord[50];
//int ArticleLength = ArticleLength(article);
KillPunct(article);
MakeLower(article);
LowerDictionary(dictionary);
ArticleNextWord(article, ArticleWord, ArticleLength, dictionary);
int strncmp(char *ArticleWord, char *DictionaryWord, int n);
int main(void); {
    FILE *Dictionary;
    FILE *Article;
    int words_read;
    char* p;

    Dictionary = fopen("dictionary.txt", "r");
    if (Dictionary == 0) {
        printf("The Dictionary is Empty");
        return;
    }
    Article = fopen("article.txt", "r");
    if (Article == 0) {
        printf("The Article Has No Words");
        return;
    }
    p = dictionary;
    p = fgets(p, 100, Dictionary);
    while (p != 0) {
        while (*p != '\0') {
            p += 1;
        }
        p = fgets(p, 100, Dictionary);
    }
    p = article;
    words_read = fread(p, 1, 1000, Article);
    p += words_read;
    while (words_read != 0) {
        words_read = fread(p, 1, 1000, Article);
        p += words_read;
        }
    *p = 0;
    }
spellCheck(article, dictionary);


int ArticlePosition = 0;
int DictionaryPosition = 0;

void DictionaryNextWord(char dictionary[], char DictionaryWord[]) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; dictionary[DictionaryPosition] != '\n'; i += 1) {
        DictionaryWord[i] = dictionary[DictionaryPosition];
        DictionaryPosition += 1;
    }
}
int OneLetter(char c){
    if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void KillPunct(char article[]) {
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; article[i] != 0; i += 1) {
        if (OneLetter(article[i])){
            article[j] = article[i];
            j += 1;
        }
        else if (!OneLetter(article[i])){
            article[j] = ' ';
            j += 1;
        }
    }
}

void MakeLower(char article[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for (i += 1; article[i] != 0; i += 1) {
        if (article[i] >= 'A' && article[i] <= 'Z')
            article[i] = article[i] + 32;
    }
}

void LowerDictionary(char dictionary[]){
    int i = 0;
    for (i; dictionary[i] != 0; i += 1){
        if (dictionary[i] >= 'A' && dictionary[i] <= 'Z'){
            dictionary[i] = dictionary[i] + 32;
        }
    }
}

int ArticleLength(char article[]){
    int count = 0;
    while (article[count] != 0)
        count += 1;
    return count;
}

void ArticleNextWord(char article[], char ArticleWord[], int ArticleLength, char DictionaryWord[], char dictionary[]){
    int j, i;
check:
    int counter = strlen(ArticleWord);
    while (!OneLetter(article[ArticlePosition])){
        if (article[ArticlePosition] == 0){
            return;
        }
        ArticlePosition += 1;
    }
    for (j = 0; article[ArticlePosition] != ' ' || ArticlePosition == ArticleLength; j += 1){
        ArticleWord[j] = article[ArticlePosition];
        ArticlePosition += 1;
    }
    if (counter < 2){
        goto check;
    }
    ArticleWord[j + 1] = 0;
    while (!strcmp(ArticleWord, DictionaryWord, strlen(ArticleWord))){
        DictionaryNextWord(dictionary, DictionaryWord);
    }
    if (strcmp(ArticleWord, DictionaryWord, strlen(ArticleWord)))
        return;
    printf(ArticleWord);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include the header which defines `strlen` and `strcmp`

```
#include <string.h>
```

Later: Edits to your question have removed the other includes.  You also need to `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Actually, it does look like he is supposed to implement `strncmp`, or...? Because if he includes string.h it, the local function strncmp will collide with the old legacy function strncmp in that header.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I wonder if the forward declaration is a mistake?  This'd seem like a rather convoluted example if the goal was to implement `strncmp`.  If the OP is supposed to already know the standard string functions (as hinted at by use of `strlen` and `strcmp`?), it'd seem odd to expect him/her to continue using a local version.

Comment: And btw it was _your_ edit who altered his code and removed the includes. So maybe the decent thing would be to restore your invalid edit, rather than to expect the OP to do it? I have fixed it now...

Comment: I don't think I removed the includes.  They were incorrectly indented originally; my edit changed this so they were displayed as code.  The OP made a later edit which removed them I think.  If I've mis-read the edit history, apologies to the OP...

Comment: It says: error C2664: 'void ArticleNextWord(char [],char [],int,char [])' : cannot convert argument 3 from 'int (__cdecl *)(char [])' to 'int'